# Spring Boot, ultilizar outro campo de busca alem do @id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou fazendo uma API com Java com Spring boot e gostaria que ele buscasse pelo CPF e não pelo ID;

```
http://localhost:8080/pacientes/ID

http://localhost:8080/pacientes/Cpf (sera informado pelo usuario)
http://localhost:8080/pacientes/cpf->http://localhost:8080/pacientes/77777785558
```

e tenho o seguinte campos na classe PACIENTE;

o ID gostaria de deixar como esta, para ele criar,deleta, e alterar, na url, gostaria de buscar pelo CPF.

Classe Domain

```
@Entity
public class Paciente implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private Long cpf;
    private String nome;

    public Paciente() {}

    public Paciente(Integer id,Long cpf, String nome) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.cpf = cpf
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    // GETTERS E SETTERS
}
```

PacienteRepository

```
@Repository
public interface PacienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Paciente, Integer> {

}
```

PacienteResource

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "capientes")
public class PacienteResource {

    @Autowired
    PacienteService PacienteService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Paciente> buscar(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Paciente obj = PacienteService.findId(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);

    }
}
```

PacienteService

```
@Service
public class PacienteService {

    @Autowired
    PacienteRepository repo;



    public Paciente findId(Integer id) {
        Optional<Paciente> obj = repo.findById(id); 
        return obj.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Objeto não encontrado! ID: " + id + ", Tipo"+ PacienteService.class.getName()));

    }


    public Paciente insert (Paciente obj) {
        obj.setId(null);
        return repo.save(obj);
    }
    public Paciente update (Paciente obj) {
        findId(obj.getId());
        return repo.save(obj);
    }
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        findId(id);
        try {
            repo.deleteById(id);
        }   
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
             throw new DateIntegrityException("Não é possível excluir uma Paciente ");

        }

    }
}
```

está funcionado , porem eu preciso ao invés de buscar  pelo ID, quero buscar pelo cpf, que a pessoa ira informa, ficando assim:

```
http://localhost:8080/pacientes/77777788898788
```

Hoje ele esta buscando paciente somente pelo ID

```
http://localhost:8080/pacientes/1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu Repository deve ser capaz de buscar no banco pelo CPF, ficando assim:

```
@Repository
public interface PacienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Paciente, Integer> {

    Optional<Paciente> findByCpf(Long cpf);
}
```

Na sua classe service `PacienteService`, acrescente agora o método para efetuar a busca pelo CPF:

```
public Paciente findCPF(Long cpf) {
    Optional<Paciente> obj = repo.findByCpf(cpf); 
    return obj.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Objeto não encontrado! CPF: " + cpf + ", Tipo"+ PacienteService.class.getName()));
}
```

Por fim, construa seu EndPoint no resource `PacienteResource`:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{cpf}")
public ResponseEntity<Paciente> buscar(@PathVariable Long cpf) {
    Paciente obj = PacienteService.findCpf(cpf);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
}
```